# Curl Put respose is Invalid json for Java type interface java.util.Map"

Tags: curl

I am using below command:

```
curl -X PUT http://xyz:8080/v1/project/086517a8-df1a-47a7-bcc7-056b08bd76d4?pretty -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

and the response to this command is:
"Invalid json for Java type interface java.util.Map"

Please suggest how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, you should pass 'Accept' header.  And where is your JSON encoded data?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to add an argument to your PUT request, something like:

```
curl -X PUT http://xyz:8080/v1/project/086517a8-df1a-47a7-bcc7-056b08bd76d4?pretty -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "name=myName"
```

Or your server is not doing the transformation correctly. Your request likely creates something empty which the server probably doesn't like.